# Token issues in b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, owin, azure-ad-b2c

I have created one b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi type application. But After 20 min or after sometime(nearly 30 min not sure) My WebApp is throwing exception during the Ajax call saying 401(Unauthorized). This exception is coming when ajax call hitting the WebApp controller So this error is coming from OWIN middleware not sure why.

**My Startup.cs settings are**

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(_aadB2CPasswordResetPolicy));
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(_aadB2CSignInPolicy));
        }

        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            if (context.Exception is OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException &&
                context.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX10316"))
            {
                // Redirect to the originally requested URL
                context.Response.Redirect(context.Request.Uri.PathAndQuery);
            }
            else
            {
                var trackingId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                _telemetry.TrackException(
                    context.Exception,
                    new Dictionary<string, string> {{"SignInErrorTrackingId", trackingId}});
                context.Response.Redirect($"/Home/SignInError?trackingId={trackingId}");
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
        {
            return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
                // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
                MetadataAddress = string.Format(_aadInstance, _tenant, policy),
                AuthenticationType = policy,

                // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
                ClientId = _clientId,
                RedirectUri = _redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = _redirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                },
                Scope = "openid",
                ResponseType = "id_token",

                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    SaveSigninToken = true,
                },
            };
        }
    }
```

**If I am modifying the code**

`app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { SlidingExpiration = true, ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60) });,`

And adding the below setting in OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
`UseTokenLifetime = false`,

Then My WebApp is working for 1 hour and after that again I am facing the 401 Unauthorized. This time my WEAPI giving this error because by default token is valid for 1 hour I guess.

**Question** : How can I manage the token issues if the token is expired after 1 hour during ajax call ? and What is best setting that I should have So that my middleware will not give me 401 after 20 min or some random time ?

Kindly Ignore if something I am doing terribly wrong. I am very new to this and don't have much idea.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track! There are a couple things that you need to be aware of:

All tokens returned by Azure AD B2C have an expiration time. After x minutes, your id token expired. You need to get a new id token again by going through the sign-in process again.

Because it is annoying to sign in every x minutes, you can request a refresh token when a user logs in for the first time. When the id token expires, you can send the refresh token to Azure AD B2C to get a new id token.

Part of the refresh token implementation is automated by the library, but this is what you need to implement:

1. Request a code in addition to an id token by adding 'code' in the responseType variable, and adding 'offline_access' in the scope variable.
2. Exchange the code for a refresh token and store the token inside a cache.
3. Get the token from the cache before making a call to the web api. If the token is expired, the library will automatically renew it for you before pulling it out of the cache.

All of this is done in this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-api-dotnet). You just need to update the scope (the default responseType when you don't specify it is "code id_token").

**Note:** We enabled the use of [access tokens](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-ad-b2c-access-tokens-now-in-public-preview/) and updated the sample with it. Please use this updated sample. Your code reflects the old sample. I also recommend using access tokens instead of id tokens when calling the web API.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. As you suggested I implemented the refresh token part. its working fine as of now.  But now I am getting very frequent issue while login to Azure page. ie. I am getting error 400 **Request Header is Too Large** this issue is coming because now my cookie is too large, due to keeping all the tokens in the context. Any suggestion for this issue. Well I am deleting all the cookie when user is getting sign out. But its look like sometime it is not working.